# How to show Laplacian is surjective on Schwartz space?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $S$ be the space of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb R^3$, and let $\Delta$ be the Laplacian operator on $S$. How to show $\Delta$ is surjective? I'm not familiar with PDE. Maybe the solution of $\Delta f=g$ of $f$ exists, then I don't know how to show $f$ is a Schwartz function. Could you post an answer or some references? Thanks.

Comment: It is not surjective. Notice that the integral of $\Delta f$ is $0$, so you don't get all the functions from $S$.

Comment: @user8268 Why the integral of $\Delta f$ is 0? I have totally forgotten PDE...

Comment: Take the Fourier transform of $\nabla f =g $

Comment: the integral of $\partial f/\partial x$ is $0$ (integrate first by $x$ and then by $y$ and by $z$); from here you should see why